# JQuery : Add a confirm handler with bind/on and trigger functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, bind, confirm

I'm trying to add a confirm box to many links, button, or inputs, on the click event.

I can't use location.href, submit(), or other specific features because :

- location.href, for example, won't work on a submit button,
- location.href, for example, won't trigger other bound handlers.

So what I need to use is the trigger() function, that theorically execute all the handlers AND the native action. The "difficult" part is to execute all handlers, EXCEPT the handler which pop the confirm box.

Here is my code :

```
$('a, button, input[type="submit"]').each(function() {

    var oButton = $(this);

    oButton.on('click.pending', function(oEvent) {
        console.log('click !');
        oEvent.preventDefault();

        var oDialog = $('<div class="dialog-example">[Question] ?</div>').dialog({
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function() {
                    console.log('cancelled !');
                    // Nothing to do
                    oDialog.dialog('close');
                },
                Ok: function() {
                    console.log('confirmed !');
                    // Trigger the rest of the handlers AND the native action, BUT not this one, so this dialog is not used
                    // Problem : nothing happens here
                    oButton.trigger('click.confirmed');
                    oDialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Thanks in advance ! ;)

Comment: Could you create a fiddle please ?

Comment: The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Chicna/EerEF/2/

Comment: In this case, for the "clarity" of the code, i use something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/EerEF/4/ (oops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

```
oButton.off('click.pending').trigger('click').get(0).click();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hH9ba/show/)

Comment: Nice ! But the check is done just once. I need to rebound the handler after your code I guess.

Comment: Clicking on anchor or submit is supposed to redirect user to new page or reload current page, so usually, you shouldn't have to rebind event. That's said, you could still use a referenced function and rebind it after firing event: http://jsfiddle.net/EHkGq/show/

Comment: You're right, anchor or submit is supposed to redirect, but for example, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap tabbable tabs : http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs.

Comment: I'm rebinding it only if the handler itself is removed.